# Calling a method in a different view and then showing that view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a viewController called "chooseDateViewController" where in the .m file it takes input from the user and puts into a string. I have another viewController called "showTable" where I have a custom made table that takes the dates in the string. the table is generated (in showTable.m) based on the dates (which are strings).

I want to be able to call "showTableViewController" view controller when the user enters the data and presses a button so then they are taken to the showTableViewController with there dates nicely displayed but my problem is I cannot pass the data from the "chooseDate" View controller to a method in "showTable". This is how I did it but it is not working... I tried to NSLog it but its not even entering the function. If anyone knows why, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
// In chooseDateViewController.m
-(void) sendValue { 
   NSString *date= @"July 25 2012";

   UIViewController *view5 = [[showTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"showTableViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:view5 animated:YES];

   [view5 receiveNumbers:date]; //trigger the method in showTable.m
   [view5 release];
}


// showTableViewController.m
-(void) receiveNumbers: (id) sender {
   NSLog (@"data received is %@", sender);
}
```

Comment: Is the showTableViewController being pushed? Is the program even running since there is you have "July 25 2012" instead of @"July 25 2012"?

Comment: Yes it is and sorry it is running just forgot the "@"

Comment: hmm.. your code should work.. Try calling 

[view5 kkk:date]. See is calling a non-existent method on the class ends up in the same behavior.

Comment: it crashes... as expected. Any other ideas? thanks

Comment: My only other advice for you would be to put break points to see if the NSLog method is being called in the receiveNumbers method.

Comment: how is your "date" defined in show, can we see that?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can initialize the viewController with the information, so for example, you can have a line that is like:

```
UIViewController *view5 = [[showTableViewController alloc]  initWithSomeInfo: (the structure that houses the data)];
```

Then in the custom init method of the showTableViewController, you can process the data before you are pushing the view controller.

I hope this helps,
Tams

Here is some code that you were looking for:
In the showTableViewController, you have have a variable to hold the passed in information so:

```
    - (id)initWithSomeInfo(NSArray*)info{ 
self = [super init]; 
if(self){
myOwnVariable = info; 
[self processInfo:myOwnVariable];
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you tams! I am fairly new to this so if you do not mind showing me what you meant with "Then in the custom init method of the showTableViewController, you can process the data before you are pushing the view controller."? Thanks again